MIPS array loop assignment
im having trouble coding the instruction type for each of the pointers in the array for a class assignment. the purpose of the program is to loop through an array of pointers and parse each pointer to find the opcode value. the opcode value is then used to determine what instruction type each pointer is.
so far ive gotten the pointers and the opcode to print out correctly. my issue is with the process_instruction function and implementing it into the loop_array.
here is the code im working with now. any help with this is greatly appreciated.
# Author: 
# Date: 
# Description: Parse MIPS instructions based on opcode and print message
    

.globl main, decode_instruction, process_instruction, print_hex_info            # Do not remove this line
    

# Data for the program goes here
.data
    process: .asciiz "\nNow processing instruction "
    opcode_num: .asciiz "\tThe opcode value is: "
    newLine: .asciiz "\n"
    

    # number of test cases
    CASES: .word 5
    # array of pointers (addresses) to the instructions
    instructions:   .word 0x01095020,       # add $t2, $t0, $t1
            .word 0x1220002C,       # beqz $s1, label
            .word 0x3C011001,       # lw $a0, label($s0)
            .word 0x24020004,       # li $v0, 4
            .word 0x08100002        # j label
        
    inst_0:     .asciiz "\tR-Type Instruction\n"
    inst_other: .asciiz "\tUnsupported Instruction\n"
    inst_2_3:   .asciiz "\tUnconditional Jump\n"
    inst_4_5:   .asciiz "\tConditional Jump\n"
    

    # You may use this array of labels to print the different instructions type messages
    inst_types: .word inst_0, inst_other, inst_2_3, inst_2_3, inst_4_5, inst_4_5
    

# Code goes here
.text
main:
    # Task 1A: Loop over the array of instructions 
    li $t0, 0                           # Initialize counter to 0
    la $t1, instructions                 # Load base address of instructions array
    li $t2, 5                            # Total number of instructions


loop_array:
    bge $t0, $t2, end_main               # Exit loop if counter >= number of instructions

    # Load the current instruction
    lw $t3, 0($t1)                       # Load the instruction at current array index

    # Call print_hex_info for the instruction processing message
    la $a0, process                      # Load the "process" message
    move $a1, $t3                        # Move the current instruction to $a1
    jal print_hex_info                   # Print the processing message

    # Call decode_instruction
    move $a0, $t3                        # Pass the instruction to decode_instruction
    jal decode_instruction               # Extract the opcode

    # Call print_hex_info for opcode
    la $a0, opcode_num                   # Load the "opcode_num" message
    move $a1, $v0                        # Use the opcode from decode_instruction
    jal print_hex_info                   # Print the opcode

    # Update the index and pointer for the next iteration
    addi $t0, $t0, 1                     # Increment counter
    addi $t1, $t1, 4                     # Move to the next word in the array

    j loop_array                         # Repeat the loop
        
end_main:
    li $v0, 10      # 10 is the exit program syscall
    syscall         # execute call
###############################################################
    

## Other procedures here
decode_instruction:
    # Save registers to Stack
    subi $sp, $sp, 8    # Allocate space for two registers
    sw $s0, 4($sp)      # Save $s0
    sw $ra, 0($sp)      # Save $ra

    # Your function "real" code begins here
    move $s0, $a0       # Move input instruction to $s0
    andi $s1, $s0, 0xFC000000  # Isolate opcode (bits 31-26)
    srl $v0, $s1, 26    # Right shift 26 positions to get the opcode

    # Restore registers from Stack
    lw $s0, 4($sp)      # Restore $s0
    lw $ra, 0($sp)      # Restore $ra
    addi $sp, $sp, 8    # Deallocate stack space

    jr $ra              # Return to the caller  
process_instruction:
    subi $sp, $sp, 8                # Allocate stack space for $ra and $a0
    sw $ra, 4($sp)                  # Save $ra
    sw $a0, 0($sp)                  # Save opcode

    lw $t0, 0($sp)                  # Load opcode into $t0

    li $t1, 0
    beq $t0, $t1, r_type
    li $t1, 2
    beq $t0, $t1, j_type
    li $t1, 3
    beq $t0, $t1, j_type
    li $t1, 4
    beq $t0, $t1, c_type
    li $t1, 5
    beq $t0, $t1, c_type
    j unsupported

r_type:
    la $a0, inst_0
    j print

j_type:
    la $a0, inst_2_3
    j print

c_type:
    la $a0, inst_4_5
    j print

unsupported:
    la $a0, inst_other

print:
    jal print_hex_info               # Use print_hex_info to print the instruction type message

    lw $ra, 4($sp)                   # Restore $ra
    addi $sp, $sp, 8                 # Restore the stack pointer
    jr $ra                           # Return to the caller
###############################################################
# Print Message based on opcode type
#
# $a0 - Message to print
# $a1 - Value to print
# Uses $s0: address of string for $a0 (required)
# Uses $s1: value from $a1 (required)
print_hex_info:
    ##### Begin Save registers to Stack
    subi  $sp, $sp, 36
    sw   $ra, 32($sp)
    sw   $s0, 28($sp)
    sw   $s1, 24($sp)
    sw   $s2, 20($sp)
    sw   $s3, 16($sp)
    sw   $s4, 12($sp)
    sw   $s5, 8($sp)
    sw   $s6, 4($sp)
    sw   $s7, 0($sp)
    ##### End Save registers to Stack
    

    # Now your function begins here
    move $s0, $a0
    move $s1, $a1
        
    li $v0, 4               # print message
    move $a0, $s0
    syscall
        
    li $v0, 34              # print address in hex value
    move $a0, $s1
    syscall
        
    li $v0, 4               # print message
    la $a0, newLine
    syscall
    

end_print_hex_info:
    ##### Begin Restore registers from Stack
    lw   $ra, 32($sp)
    lw   $s0, 28($sp)
    lw   $s1, 24($sp)
    lw   $s2, 20($sp)
    lw   $s3, 16($sp)
    lw   $s4, 12($sp)
    lw   $s5, 8($sp)
    lw   $s6, 4($sp)
    lw   $s7, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 36
    ##### End Restore registers from Stack
        
    jr $ra
###############################################################

this is the output im getting with this code, these outputs are correct except for the instruction type is not functioning correctly
Now processing instruction 0x01095020
    The opcode value is: 0x00000000

Now processing instruction 0x1220002c
    The opcode value is: 0x00000004

Now processing instruction 0x3c011001
    The opcode value is: 0x0000000f

Now processing instruction 0x24020004
    The opcode value is: 0x00000009

Now processing instruction 0x08100002
    The opcode value is: 0x00000002

so far i have written the code for the instruction type and tried implementing it into the loop_array. all of the variations ive tried to put in to loop_array have either created a never ending loop, only printed the first pointer in the array with the wrong instruction type, or all the of outputs are comprised of 0's

Show the non-working code. Use your simulator/debugger to single step and see where it goes wrong. In general, be sure to preserve registers you need. Better yet, follow the conventions.

Are you having a problem developing a decoding approach / algorithm, or with something specific about a MIPS insrtuction sequence in assembly?

to be completely honest im horrible at writing code and my main code is python. ive gotten the loop to pull the pointers in the array and the opcode values are printing correctly. my problem is i cant figure out how to get the value stored from the decode_ instruction to compare to the instruction type

How do you do it in Python?
